# include paths setting in keil

Tags: path, keil

I know the path has an error.

But I don't know what to do in **ARM-keil**.

The only thing I can think of is that I have to change all the paths there, But I do not think this is the right way.

Do you have any other way?

I just want to add '..\' and add it to the whole thing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The best option for include path was same as you are doing
go to Target Option  and select your include folder by browse option

second option is use direct include path in every were you are including file

example

## include "E:\Digital\Project_25\LPC4333\Firmware\system.h"